# Bulk create model objects in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a lot of objects to save in database, and so I want to create Model instances with that.

With django, I can create all the models instances, with `MyModel(data)`, and then I want to save them all.

Currently, I have something like that:

```
for item in items:
    object = MyModel(name=item.name)
    object.save()
```

I'm wondering if I can save a list of objects directly, eg:

```
objects = []
for item in items:
    objects.append(MyModel(name=item.name))
objects.save_all()
```

How to save all the objects in one transaction?

Comment: It seems the ball is rolling on implementing a fix for this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19527

Comment: wondering for list.save_all ? You could almost answer yourself just paraphrase that wondering and use 2 first words from your topic question.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use [`bulk_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method. It's standard in Django now.

**Example:**

```
Entry.objects.bulk_create([
    Entry(headline="Django 1.0 Released"),
    Entry(headline="Django 1.1 Announced"),
    Entry(headline="Breaking: Django is awesome")
])
```

Comment: Changed in Django 1.10:
Support for setting primary keys on objects created using bulk_create() when using PostgreSQL was added.

Answer (score 132):

as of the django development, there exists [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) as an object manager method which takes as input an array of objects created using the class constructor. check out django docs

Comment: Django's docs for `bulk_create`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Comment: But remember bulk_create has some limitations like it does not create primary keys if it is an AutoField which save() does automatically.

Comment: @HiteshGarg, Is that still true now days?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda, yes it is still true. It is right there in the documentation: `If the model’s primary key is an AutoField it does not retrieve and set the primary key attribute, as save() does, unless the database backend supports it (currently only PostgreSQL).`

Comment: How many objects should I bulk_create each time? Should I base on something (RAM, reality cases, etc.) to set the batch number? Let say I got to create billions records?

Comment: Using **Django 3.0.x** and I confirm that using `bulk_create()` does not trigger any signals. I wonder why.

Comment: It is documented: "The model’s save() method will not be called, and the pre_save and post_save signals will not be sent."

Answer (score 9):

```
name = request.data.get('name')
period = request.data.get('period')
email = request.data.get('email')
prefix = request.data.get('prefix')
bulk_number = int(request.data.get('bulk_number'))

bulk_list = list()
for _ in range(bulk_number):
    code = code_prefix + uuid.uuid4().hex.upper()
    bulk_list.append(
        DjangoModel(name=name, code=code, period=period, user=email))

bulk_msj = DjangoModel.objects.bulk_create(bulk_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

worked for me to use manual transaction handling for the loop(postgres 9.1):

```
from django.db import transaction
with transaction.atomic():
    for item in items:
        MyModel.objects.create(name=item.name)
```

in fact it's not the same, as 'native' database bulk insert, but it allows you to avoid/descrease transport/orms operations/sql query analyse costs

Comment: This slightly changed. Now transaction does not have `commit_on_success` anymore. 
You should use `transaction.atomic()`
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861207/is-transaction-atomic-same-as-transaction-commit-on-success

Comment: This method doesn't exactly scale, because you are practically making a create on every for  loop pass which equals a db interaction per pass. bulk create seems to work faster.

Comment: Yeah this was answered a quite while ago, you should use bulk_create() now for this

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to bulk-create entities from column-separated file, leaving aside all unquoting and un-escaping routines:

```
SomeModel(Model):
    @classmethod
    def from_file(model, file_obj, headers, delimiter):
        model.objects.bulk_create([
            model(**dict(zip(headers, line.split(delimiter))))
            for line in file_obj],
            batch_size=None)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using create will cause one query per new item. If you want to reduce the number of INSERT queries, you'll need to use something else.

I've had some success using the Bulk Insert snippet, even though the snippet is quite old.
Perhaps there are some changes required to get it working again.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/446/

Answer (score 2):

Check out this blog post on the [bulkops](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2011/09/20/bulk-inserts-django/) module.

On my django 1.3 app, I have experienced significant speedup.

Answer (score -29):

The easiest way is to use the `create` Manager method, which creates and saves the object in a single step.

```
for item in items:
    MyModel.objects.create(name=item.name)
```

Comment: +1. If `name` is unique and duplicate inputs are possible then it would be a good idea to use `get_or_create`.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Model.objects.create is equivalent to object = MoModel(..) object.save().  And this does not do it in one transaction...