# Django storing a lot of data in table

Tags: python, django

Right now, I use this code to save the data to the database-

```
for i in range(len(companies)):
    for j in range(len(final_prices)):
      linechartdata = LineChartData()
      linechartdata.foundation = company //this refers to a foreign-key of a different model
      linechartdata.date = finald[j]
      linechartdata.price = finalp[j]
      linechartdata.save()
```

Now `len(companies)` can vary from [3-50] and `len(final_prices)` can vary from somewhere between [5000-10000]. I know its a very inefficient way to store it in the database and takes a lot of time. What should I do to make it effective and less time consuming?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk create model objects in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608487/bulk-create-model-objects-in-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to store them in the database you might check [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create). From the documents:

> This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many objects there are):

Although, I never personally used it for that many objects, docs say it can. This could make your code more efficient in terms of hitting the database and using multiple `save()`.

Basically to try; create list of objects (without saving) and then use `bulk_create`. Like this:

```
arr = []
for i in range(len(companies)):
    for j in range(len(final_prices)):
        arr.append(
           LineChartData(
              foundation = company,
              date = finald[j],
              price = finalp[j]
            )
        )
LineChartData.objects.bulk_create(arr)
```

Comment: I know there exists a bulk_create method but I can not find the right example to understand how to use it

Comment: If you're going to just rewrite the answer linked as a duplicate, at least improve upon it. Add sample code, for instance.

Comment: @spectras sorry man, I didn't really see your comment. Should I delete this?

Comment: No, but it would be much better if you could add a short code sample showing how to use `bulk_create`. Especially as ThatBird is struggling with that.

Comment: Just added an example for your code. Hope it helps @ThatBird

Comment: Thanks, it helped !