# Send message to all Users in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

i was about to create a function that sends message to all members Using `forloop`
but then i thought that this method gonna take alot of time in process if there is a plenty of members...

so i came to ask if is there any better method to ignore `forloop` and smooth the process.

**Model:**

```
class TblExamNotification(models.Model):

    exam = ForeignKey(TblExam,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    user = ForeignKey(Members,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    is_seen = BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**Views:**

```
for member in memebers.exclude(member = request.user):
           notif_obj = Members.objects.create(user=member , exam=exam_obj)
           notif_obj .save()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk create model objects in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608487/bulk-create-model-objects-in-django)

Comment: no it didnt help !

Comment: @ImThePeak for loop can't be removed, but you can optimize db hits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a list of all notifications you want to use, then save these in bulk with [**`bulk_create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

```
items = [
    TblExamNotification(user=member , exam=exam_obj)
    for member in memebers.exclude(member=request.user)
]

TblExamNotification.objects.bulk_create(items)
```

The bottleneck is (very) likely not the `for` loop itself, but the fact that you used a *lot* of queries to the database.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with for loop. The issue is you are making DB query on every creation of the Members object.

You can reduce multiple hits using bulk create which makes query only once to create multiple objects.

Ref: [Bulk create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

```py
member_objs = [Members(user=member, exam=exam_obj) for member in members.exclude(member=request.user)]
Members.objects.bulk_create(member_objs)
```